# Possible unique combinations of 2 values 5 different ways

Tags: mysql, matrix

This is so simple but I'm not sure what the best way is to go about calculating this and I'm new to data programming. 
I have a table of 5 columns and 2 values Y and N. How do I get all unique possible combinations of Y and N in rows? This could be any two values but I am using Y and N. Screenshot and visual below of me trying to do this by hand.

```
YYYYY
NNNNN
YNYNY
NYNYN
NYYYY
NNYYY
NNNYY
NNNNY
```

Comment: Is there a particular programming language you're trying to do this in?

Comment: I'm really not sure. Maybe something like R or mySQL?

Comment: People are down voting this because you haven't provided any of your own code attempts. Please show us what isn't working, and assume that no one will click on your links. (i.e. copy and paste your code into your question

Comment: This is really more of a math question than a sql one; searching (google) for combinations and permutations would probably be beneficial.

Comment: @Mozahler the problem is, I don't know how to code it! I'm working in a database table and have little knowledge of how to do this. I have tried adding a screenshot of the csv file

Comment: I'm glad Eric came to the rescue and you found your answer.

Comment: @Uueerdo you led me to the right answer and it is more about math! I was able to create a CSV list using this tool and replacing a,b with Y,N.  https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a simpler problem.  How many unique combinations are there of *zero* Y or N ?  There's only one: the combination that contains no elements.

How many unique combinations are there of *one* Y or N?  There are two:

```
N Y
```

How many unique combinations are there of *two* Y or N?  There are four:

```
NN NY YN YY
```

Three? There are eight:

```
NNN NNY NYN NYY YNN YNY YYN YYY
```

0 has 1, 1 has 2, 2 has 4, 3 has 8, ... You should have guessed by now that there are two to the k combinations of k Y Ns.

We form new combinations from old combinations by the following algorithm:

- If we have zero elements, the empty list is the result.
- If we have k > 0 elements, make the list of k-1 elements.  "Double" the list and extend each pair with N or Y.

In case that last example is not clear, let's look at 3 again.  We start by solving the problem for 2:

```
NN NY YN YY
```

Then we double it

```
NN NN NY NY YN YN YY YY
```

Then we add N, Y, N, Y, N, Y, N, Y to get

```
NNN NNY NYN NYY YNN YNY YYN YYY
```

In data languages this operation is the Cartesian Product of a sequence with *itself*. It is also called a "cross join" because it is notated in algebra with a X cross. This is `{N,Y} x {N,Y} x {N,Y} x {N,Y} x {N,Y}`.

EXERCISE: How would you do it for a sequence with three elements, {A, B, C}?  How many combinations of k elements are there?

EXERCISE: How many ways are there of ordering 10 Y-or-Ns such that there are exactly 5 of each?  How would you produce *those* combinations?  Again, *start with a simpler problem and reason your way towards the harder problem*.

FURTHER READING: If you are interested in how to do these operations in C# I have written many articles on them over the years:

https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/

https://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/

https://ericlippert.com/2014/10/13/producing-combinations-part-one/

Answer (score 1):

I'd use CROSS JOIN of five row sources.

```
SELECT t1.custom1
     , t2.custom2
     , t3.custom3
     , t4.custom4
     , t5.custom5
  FROM ( SELECT 'Y' AS custom1 UNION ALL SELECT 'N' ) t1 
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 'Y' AS custom2 UNION ALL SELECT 'N' ) t2 
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 'Y' AS custom3 UNION ALL SELECT 'N' ) t3 
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 'Y' AS custom4 UNION ALL SELECT 'N' ) t4 
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 'Y' AS custom5 UNION ALL SELECT 'N' ) t5 
 ORDER
    BY t1.custom1 DESC
     , t2.custom2 DESC
     , t3.custom3 DESC
     , t4.custom4 DESC
     , t5.custom5 DESC
```